# Los adverbios entre el artículo definido y el sustantivo

Tags: gramática, artículos

Observé varias oraciones:

*"Paloma Cuevas, la eterna discreción de **la todavía esposa**: así prepara su futuro sin Enrique Ponce."*

"*El legendario excampeón de peso pesado se enfrentará **al también estadounidense** Roy Jones Jr.*"

*"Un sobrino del actor muere por lesiones cerebrales cinco años después de sufrir una fuerte caída. A su esposa, **la también actriz** Natasha Richardson, le ocurrió lo mismo en 2009"*

Preguntas:

1. ¿Se puede usar tanto con el artículo definido como con el artículo indefinido? ¿O solo es posible implementar el artículo definido?
2. ¿Cuántas palabras y cuáles se pueden usar entre  el artículo definido y el sustantivo? Solo puedo recordar "*el **entonces** presidente*".

Para aclarar, no hablo del caso del adjetivo entre el artículo definido y el sustantivo ("*la supuesta contaminación*"), dado que esta es una situación estandar.

Comment: ... el **entonces y ahora todavía** director del Instituto Nacional de Alergias y Enfermedades Infecciosas, el responsable de liderar las respuestas ... en https://www.lavanguardia.com/opinion/20200413/48450396631/imprevision.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En primer lugar, debemos decir que no es común que el adverbio modifique al sustantivo. Es más: considero que no lo modifica directamente en los ejemplos mencionados.

En su artículo ["El problema del adverbio como parte de la oración"](https://minerva.usc.es/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10347/3457/pg_123-146_verba33.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), Luis Alberto Hernando Cuadrado explica en la nota 41 (página 16 del pdf, página 138 de la publicación) el proceso por el cual un adverbio puede ingresar a un grupo nominal:

> En construcciones del tipo de *el entonces Presidente del
> Gobierno...*, catalizados los elementos elididos, *que era*, obtenemos
> como resultado *el [que era] entonces Presidente del Gobierno...*,
> donde la primitiva oración *era entonces Presidente del Gobierno*, en
> la que el adverbio *entonces* desempeña la función de aditamento, y el
> grupo sintagmático *Presidente del Gobierno* la de atributo, es
> transpuesta a adjetivo con el *que* y posteriormente a sustantivo por
> medio del artículo.

Los adverbios temporales (*antes, ahora, entonces, todavía*) y de afirmación (*también*), entre otros, pueden ingresar al grupo nominal en función de atributo (los primeros) y de modificador oracional (el segundo) a través de la elisión del verbo copulativo y del pronombre relativo:

- el [que era] entonces presidente
- el [que es] ahora amigo
- la [que era] todavía esposa
- la [que es] también actriz

También podemos encontrar adverbios intensificadores o cuantificadores, en cuyo caso se potencian o degradan las cualidades propias del sustantivo. En este caso, el sustantivo está adjetivizado y la relación entre adverbio y sustantivo parece más directa que en los casos anteriores:

- el **muy poco** hombre (muy poco valiente, muy poco responsable)
- el **casi** niño (muy infantil)
- es **muy** mujer (muy femenina, muy madura)

En cuanto al artículo, es predominante - si no excluyente - el uso del artículo definido. Con respecto a la cantidad de palabras que puede encontrarse, serán tantas como puedan modificar al adverbio o frase preposicional de valor adverbial:

- el **hasta entonces** presidente
- el **sólo por ahora** amigo

También podemos pensar en frases con construcciones más complejas que, aunque improbables, serían gramaticales:

- el **por el momento y quién sabe hasta cuándo** mandatario